# How to equaly distribute columns inside a css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

In the example below I want to distribute blue and green column horizontally with equal space `between` AND `around` them

I tried various combinations with `justify-content` and `align-items` - without success

Please, help

```css
.cols{
width:calc(100% - 30px);
margin:0 auto;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:340px 140px;
background:lightblue;
height:90vh;
}

.cola{background:blue;}
.colb{background:green;}
```

```html
<div class='cols'>
<div class='cola'></div>
<div class='colb'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean here. Are you needing the grid-gap property?

Comment: @dantheman - I want to distribute columns horizontally with equal space between AND around them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you're looking for `justify-content: space-evenly`.

```css
.cols {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 340px 140px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cola {
  background: blue;
}

.colb {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='cols'>
  <div class='cola'></div>
  <div class='colb'></div>
</div>
```